# Python shebang line

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

i've seen some people write their shebang line with a space after env.
Eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Is this a typo?

I don't ever use a space. I use

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python
```

Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: I believe it makes the shebang portable across different OS's.  This is a dupe, give me a second to find it.

Comment: Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6769343/3483203

Comment: @chrisz: This is not asking about the use of `env` though, this is asking about a malformed shebang.

Comment: That isn't a malformed shebang at all.

Comment: whats the difference between the two though?

Comment: Is there even a single *nix system on which the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env/python` would work?

Comment: @chrisz: You're saying that the second one isn't malformed?

Comment: His question is, is `#!/usr/bin/env python` a typo.  It is not.  You are right however that the second one shouldn't work

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with the dupe you linked just because it's not clear to me if that question is asking about shebangs in general or about shebangs with `/usr/bin/env` specifically. Looks unclear to me.

Comment: okay. I've just come across the spaced version many times on this site and nobody has corrected it

Comment: The non-spaced version is unlikely to be valid. How are you executing these scripts? `python my_executable` or `./my_executable`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it isn't a typo! The one you are using will not work on all os's. E.G. in my Ubuntu Linux implementation 'env' is a program in /usr/bin not a directory so #!/usr/bin/env/python won't work.

Answer (score 7):

Not using a space isn't a typo, but leads to portability issues when executing the same file on different machines. The purpose of the shebang line (`#!/usr....`) is to indicate what interpreter is to be used when executing the code in the file. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Syntax):

> The form of a shebang interpreter directive is as follows:
>
> `#!interpreter [optional-arg]`
>
> in which interpreter is an absolute path to an executable program. The optional argument is a string representing a single argument.

The example you provided, `#!/usr/bin/env python`, actually indicates to the shell that the interpreter to be used when executing the file is the first python interpreter that exists in the user's path. The shebang line is written this way to [ensure portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability):

> Shebangs must specify absolute paths (or paths relative to current working directory) to system executables; this can cause problems on systems that have a non-standard file system layout. Even when systems have fairly standard paths, it is quite possible for variants of the same operating system to have different locations for the desired interpreter. Python, for example, might be in /usr/bin/python, /usr/local/bin/python, or even something like /home/username/bin/python if installed by an ordinary user.
>
> Because of this it is sometimes required to edit the shebang line after copying a script from one computer to another because the path that was coded into the script may not apply on a new machine, depending on the consistency in past convention of placement of the interpreter. For this reason and because POSIX does not standardize path names, POSIX does not standardize the feature.
>
> Often, the program /usr/bin/env can be used to circumvent this limitation by introducing a level of indirection. #! is followed by /usr/bin/env, followed by the desired command without full path, as in this example:
>
> `#!/usr/bin/env sh`